# LinnDrum (LM-2): tuning ranges for snare, toms, and congas

Tags: tuning, drum-machine

This question is about the classic 1980s drum machine known as the [LinnDrum (LM-2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinnDrum) by Linn Electronics.

Some drum sounds on the LinnDrum are tunable. I'm looking for detailed information about the tuning ranges. The user manual (available [here](https://archive.org/embed/synthmanual-linndrum-owners-manual)) contains the following information:

> *TUNING THE DRUMS: 
>
> The snare, sidestick snare, toms, and congas may be tuned approximately one octave by the knobs in the tuning section. [...]*

Asked more precisely: What are the fundamental frequencies/pitches of each of these drums with the knob all the way to the left, the right, or in center position?

I do not have access to the machine itself, only to a number of sample packs. I have analyzed several samples for the drums, but they all seem to have been recorded at unspecified knob settings or retuned in post-processing.

By the way, I do not have any commercial interest in this information. I'm just curious about this iconic instrument.

Comment: PS: I wanted to add more tags ("LinnDrum", "LM-2" and "drum-tuning") but I didn't have enough reputation points.